# Simple django filter is includes all users’ data rather than that of the logged-in user

Tags: django

I’m new to Django and have built a basic filter that does not filter according to the logged-in user’s data but rather all users’ data, which is incorrect. The filter is for an Automation class, which has a many:many relationship with the Message class (and funnily enough the exact same happens with the message filter).

Views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin', 'customer'], own_account_only=True)
def automation_list(request, pk):
    account = Account.objects.get(id=pk)
    automations = account.automation_set.all()
    filter = AutomationFilter(request.GET, queryset=automations)
    automations = filter.qs
    context = {'account': account,
               'automations': automations, 'filter': filter}
    return render(request, 'automations/automation_list.html', context)
```

Filters.py:

```
class AutomationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    start_date = DateFilter(field_name='date_joined', lookup_expr='gte')
    end_date = DateFilter(field_name='date_joined', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Automation  
        fields = '__all__' 
        exclude = ['account', 'date_created']
```

Models:

```
class Automation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Message(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    text = models.TextField()
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    automations = models.ManyToManyField('automations.Automation', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Why is the filter not just filtering according to the logged-in user? I’d have thought that I’m only passing in the user’s data via this line:

```
filter = AutomationFilter(request.GET, queryset=automations)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the automations  you are getting are indeed does not belong to the logged-in user? Due to Many to Many it's possible one automations object may belong to multiple users as well

Comment: Yes, the automations do belong to the current user. The reason I made it many:many is because one of the user's automations may belong to any of the user's messages, and vice versa, but one user's automations cannot belong to any of the other users (and same for messages)

Comment: So are you getting other users automations?? or Message objects that don't relate in any way to logged-in user?

Comment: No - I'm only getting the current logged-in user's automations, but yes - I'm getting other unrelated messages of other users in the logged-in user's filter